# display value (label name) of the clicked item

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have a page with clickable divs  that has been populated dynamically with Json. The divs contains list of items, and when i click on a specific one, i get a new page that contains the name and details of the clicked item.
My issue is that i can't figure out how to display the label (name) of the item cliked, if you can give some help. Many thanks !

Here is my JSON array:

```
$data['dataHeader'] = array('id', 'Name', 'Value');
$data['dataJson']   = array(
                        array('id1', 'Jeans', 'blablablabla'),
                        array('id2', 'Leather Jacket', 'some random description'),
                        array('id3', 'Suede Boots', 'description of boots')
                    );
```

Here is what i tried to do :

```
(function( $ ) {        
    // Plugin to clickable element
    $.fn.infoClickable = function() {
        this.each(function() {          
            // get the object
            var elm = $( this );                
            // Define click event
            elm.on("click", function(){ 
                //Get info relative to clicked element          
                var currentPage         = elm.data("page");
                loadPage_X_Content(elm);
            });
        });
    }       
    // Load page 1
    loadPage1Content();
    // Application du plug-in
    $('.clickableDiv').infoClickable();
}( jQuery ));

function loadPage_X_Content(elm){
     var nextPage    = currentPage + 1;
     var nextPageName = '#LV' + nextPage +'Content';
     arrayOfData      = reponseData;
     currentValue     = arrayOfData;
     var elm          = $( this );
     var elmID        = elm.attr("id");
     var PageContent    = '';
     PageContent  += '<div>' + elmID + '</div>';

     $.ajax({
        url : "Pages/index.php",
        type:  'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'action=loadPage' + '&ID=' + elmID,
        success: function(reponseData) {
```

> For header :

```
        LVContent += '<div class="HeaderLine">';
        $.each(arrayOfData['dataHeader'], function(currentIdx, currentValue)
        {
              if (currentIdx > 0)   PageContent += '<div class="' + arrayOfData[currentIdx] + '">'+ currentValue +'</div>';
         });
```

> For data :

```
         $.each(arrayOfData['dataJson'], function(currentIdx, currentValue){
              PageContent += '<div class="BlocLine clickableDiv" ';                 
              PageContent += ' id="' + currentIdx + "_" + currentContext + '"';
              PageContent += ' >';
              // columns
              $.each(currentValue, function(currentIdx, currentValueCol){
                   if (currentIdx > 0){
                   PageContent += '<div class=" '+ arrayOfData[currentIdx] +' "';
                   PageContent += ' >'+ currentValueCol +'</div>';                          
              }
         });
         PageContent += '</div>';
    });
    $(nextPageName).append(PageContent);
    $(nextPageName).find('.clickableDiv').infoClickable();

});
```

Comment: pls show the html, elm.attr("id") gets the id of the div not the id in your array. This only works if you set the id of your divs with the ids from the data array, so i am not sure on how you think you can get the name then...

Comment: Which one of the two arrays `$data['dataHeader']` or `$data['dataJson'] ` are you using ? Why are you making two arrays ? Normally you do `$data['dataJson'][0][0]` and it'll get 'id_jeans'. You should try associative arrays.

Comment: @JérémyFerreira i edit my post with some more code, i'm using both, the dataHeader contains header labels and dataJson contains data values

Comment: @FutureCake i edited my  post for more details. Indeed, it's me who set the ID's in the json file, should i set an attrribute name too ?

Comment: @Zee I dont get what you are trying to do here. you get the id of an element in your html. I don't know what this id contains so that is a problem. Then you create a LVelement containing a div with the id as text. then you add an other div with a class and some function that takes 2 aguments of with none a defined.. There are sooo many undefined variables in your code which make it kinda impossible to debug.. Pls post a complete example. See the link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @FutureCake i added more code in the post, hope you can understand it. i have a page1 with generated data and with dynamically clickable divs, that's why i created a jquery plugin to manage the clickable divs.<br> to be brief, i have a list of item generated dynamically with json (i give them ID's in json file), what i need is when i click in a specific item, i can get it's details and also the name of that clicked item..Everything works for me except the name, can't figure out how to display it. What i want to achieve is that working with the ID of the element i can get it's name

Answer (score 0):

The code included does not specify what elm is.

So just to clarify, is your elm:

```
 var elm = document.getElementById('theAttrDivId');
```

?

Also you're asking for the name but searching for the ID, so make sure it's:

```
 var elmID = elm.attr("name");
```

Comment: i just edited my post for more details, it's `var elm = $( this );` it's for the clickable divs